# PGFPlots Missing column data, but show all x-values regardless

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a data set where certain columns have missing data. I'd like to plot individual columns of this data on different plots with a consistently sized x-axis.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{temp.csv}
X,  Y,   Z,
A,  2,   3,
B,  3,   6,
C,  4,   nan,
D,  nan, nan,
E,  6,   nan,
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{temp.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture},
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,4},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{X},
    ]
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y={Y}] {\datatable};
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y={Z}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this document, you will see two lines for columns Y and Z. Now, if you comment out `\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y={Y}] {\datatable};`, the x-axis is reduced to the labels A and B, because column Z only contains values at those rows.

Is there a way to force a plot of only column Z to show all five labels on the x-axis?

Comment: Have you tried adding `unbounded coords=jump,` to the options of `axis`?

Comment: I did try that, but it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after fussing about this problem and posting this question, I discovered the answer. It is as simple as putting:

```
xmin=0,
xmax=4,
```

into the `axis` environment. I had assumed incorrectly that the `xtick` key would take care of the problem without having to put the limits in explicitly.

Comment: spent an hour on this. thank you!